# What database to use for a single-user sample ASP.NET application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, visual-studio

I have a sample ASP.NET application that I will use in classroom setting.  Each student will be running the application independently and it run only on their local machine.

The application needs a database, but I'd love it if the students didn't need to install any extra specific database software. Just allowing the students to click "run" and the app fires up would be perfect.  Also, students will be using everything from web developer express 2008 to visual studio ultimate 2010.

I've been looking at SQLite, and SQL Server Compact, but is there something else I'm overlooking here?  Do any version of vs.net include a local database server?

===EDIT====

Seems like SQL Server CE or SQLite would be the best solutions for what I need - Does either one have an edge over the other?  All things being equal, I would probably lean towards the SQL Server CE.

Comment: All but the Express SKUs automatically install SQL Express unless you uncheck the install.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to use the SQL Server CE, which is just a few DLL's. For SQL Server Express you need to install the server and configure it. This is not suitable in your case. SQL CE is good for local use and good integrated in VS.

Resources:
http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/compact.aspx

Answer (score 4):

Just use Use SQLite, package up the necessary dll and you have your solution.[image]

Comment: Esteban, thank you.  What do you think the advantage over SQLite would be over SQL Server CE?

Comment: What more would you like?  I would argue my post has just as much content as the ones below. If you need more information please let me know and I will provide it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you thinking of SQL Server Express? There is an option to install it within the Express versions of Visual Studio.

http://www.microsoft.com/express/Database/

Answer (score 0):

You could also consider SQLExpress.

You may also consider object and document databases like:
MongoDB
db40

Answer (score 0):

I would aim for SQL Server Express, as it is essentially a full SQL Server instance without all the bells and whistles. If there is an open source database popular in your area, like MySQL, etc., those are options, as well.

The issue I have with aiming for Compact (aka SQL CE, at least once apon a time) and SqlLite is they are not real world enough for most students. After they complete the course, it is more likely they will find work with full blown SQL Server than the small footprint databases.

It should also be noted that all of the VS SKUs (sans Express?) install SQL Express by default (you have to uncheck the install).

Comment: I didn't know the express editions install SQL Express by default. Good to know! :)

Comment: @bambino: Not sure about Express editions for VS (would have to check), but all others SKUs (mentioned in the post) do install SQL Express. Either way, SQL Express is a free download.

Answer (score 0):

[Firebird](http://www.firebirdnews.org/docs/fb2min.html) embedded can also do the job well

> The embedded version is an amazing
>   variation of the server. It is a fully
>   featured Firebird server packed in
>   just a few files. It is very easy to
>   deploy, since there is no need to
>   install the server.

Firebird dot net drivers are [regularly updated](http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/net-provider/)